# Aurelia Router __undefined

Tags: aurelia

I am trying to set up Router-Configuration for Aurelia. 
The project was created with `au new` and `au run --watch` was used to run Aurelia, which worked fine.

My Basic Structure looks like the following:

Index.html

src

--- home

------- home.html

--- app.ts

--- app.html

--- main.ts

My code for all the classes is:

```
// main.ts:    
import {Aurelia} from 'aurelia-framework'
import environment from './environment';

export function configure(aurelia: Aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .feature('resources');

  if (environment.debug) {
    aurelia.use.developmentLogging();
  }

  if (environment.testing) {
    aurelia.use.plugin('aurelia-testing');
  }

  aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot());
}

// index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Aurelia</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>

  <body aurelia-app="main">

   <script src="scripts/vendor-bundle.js" data-main="aurelia-bootstrapper"></script>
     <script src="scripts/app-bundle.js" ></script>
     <script src="./jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The 2 following classes do make problems:

```
// app.ts
import { Aurelia, PLATFORM } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { Router, RouterConfiguration } from 'aurelia-router';

export class App {
    router: Router;

    configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration, router: Router) {
        config.title = 'MyTitle';
        config.map([{
            route: [ '', 'home' ],
            name: 'home',
            moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('./home/home'),
            nav: true,
            title: 'Home'
         }
        ]);

        this.router = router;
    }
}

 // app.html
<template>
  <require from="navmenu/navmenu.html"></require>
  <require from="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css"></require>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <navmenu router.bind="router"></navmenu>
        <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:#9f0206; height:10px;">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="body-content container">
        <div class="col-lg-12 page-host">
          <router-view></router-view>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

As I understand the `<router-view></router-view>` tag is neccessary for the router. When I remove this tag, the Layout is rendered, except for the Data specified in app.ts.
With this line the browser results in the following error: [Cannot read property '__useDefault' of undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZxox.png)

What am I doing wrong? Is the router not injected or not available?

Comment: Do you not have a `home/home.ts` model class?

Comment: You must have a home.ts class